# How to convert the thunk action to saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I'm very new to redux-saga and am trying to get a simple demo working that makes an API call and performs pagination. It is my understanding that the redux-saga flow should work as follows.
The Page-Size is used to restrict the number of data to be displayed when the  api call.

```js
 const PAGE_SIZE = 1;

    export const fetchItems = page => (dispatch, getState) => {
      const state = getState();
      const offset = page * PAGE_SIZE;
      dispatch(setItemsCurrentPage(page));
      if (getIsPageFetched(state, page)) {
        return;
      }
      dispatch(fetchItemsRequest());
      fromItems.fetchItems({
        limit: PAGE_SIZE,
        offset,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          const pageCount = Math.ceil(response.count / PAGE_SIZE);
          dispatch(fetchItemsResponse({
            items: response.results,
            page,
            pageCount,
          }));
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

> selector.js
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Direct selector to the container state domain
>  */
> const selectState = () => state =>
>   state.get("selectState");
>
> export {
>   selectState
>  };
> ```

```
saga.js

     import { call, put, select } from "redux-saga/effects";
        import {selectState} from "./selector";    
           export function* fetchItems(page) {
              try {
              const state= yeild select(selectState())
              const offset=page * PAGE_SIZE;
              yield put(setItemsCurrentPage(page));
              /**for api calls you need use **call** method**/
              const data={limit:PAGE_SIZE,offset};
              const requestUrl = `${url}`;
              const options = {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(data)
            };
            const response = yield call(request, requestUrl, options);
            const pageCount = Math.ceil(response.count / PAGE_SIZE);
            yield put(fetchItemResponse({items:response.results,page,pageCount}))

              } catch (e) {
                yield put(LoadingError(e));
              }
            }
```

*note selectors are basically used to get data from state,in thunk we use getState() and navigate to data,But in saga you need selectors to access particular state data.**Put** is used to set data to store (basically an action),**call** is used for api hit.Go through some posts ,youtube videos or official docs for clarity,but in my opinion thunk is easier to understand.

Comment: `in saga you need selectors to access particular state data` selectors are useful, but they're not needed. `const state = yield select()` will return you the full state. `/**for api calls you need use **call** method**/` Call is needed if you want to call another saga (as opposed to a normal function), and it can be useful when unit testing, but you don't strictly need it if all you're doing is calling a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent code in redux saga would look something like this:

```
export function* watchFetch() {
  yield takeEvery('FETCH_ITEMS', fetchItems);
}

export function* fetchItems(action) {
  const offset = action.page * PAGE_SIZE;
  yield put(setItemsCurrentPage(page));
  if (yield select(getIsPageFetched, page)) {
    return;
  }
  yield put(fetchItemsRequest());
  const response = yield fromItems.fetchItems({
    limit: PAGE_SIZE,
    offset,
  });
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(response.count / PAGE_SIZE);
  yield put(fetchItemsResponse({
    items: response.results,
    page,
    pageCount,
  }));
}
```